# To receive message from 3rd party vendor via event grid

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-eventgrid

We are trying to do POC where we expect to receive message from 3rd party vendor via event grid and third party want to use AAD account if possible as they have SSO. So how can we do this so that we can receive message from them via event grid?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to create and share the endpoint for a [custom topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/custom-topics), and have them setup for sending events using AAD authentication as described in the [official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/authenticate-with-active-directory).